# Focus jumps onto the Radiobutton if I click into the "Custom Rejection Reason Textbox"

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, focus

If I click into the "Custom Rejection Reason Textbox" the focus switches to the Radiobutton. I'm still able to select it via keyboard or if I click in rapid succession into the box, and it seems like the MouseUp-Event moves the focus.

Steps to reproduce:

- Find yourself a reject-worthy suggested edit
- Click into the "Custom Rejection Reason Textbox" and hold the button
- The box now has the focus
- Let the mousebutton go, the Radiobutton receives now the focus

Seen with FF6+.

Comment: Repro confirmed (see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ETQUz/)). Aside: works fine on Chrome and Safari; in IE, it fails to select the radio at all. Gotta love standards.

Comment: @MarcGravell: Ohh...so this is in theory a bug in Firefox? But [on the other side it sounds like this behavior is correct in some way](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp). Uh...complicated.

Comment: I didn't single out any one browser for a "bug". I merely note that the behaviour is inconsistent between the three, and I would like it to be consistent (indeed, [the spec is vague](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element)).

Comment: (fixed next deploy, btw)

Comment: Sounds to me like it's not supposed to hold another editing control at all. Though, I have not much experience in reading and interpreting standards (but I know that they can be interpreted, stretched and watered like there's no tomorrow). Out of interest, what is the fix to this?

Comment: @Bobby ... yeah ... I just ended fixing up the template

Answer (score 3):

do not bump me ... thanks ... the management.