# Difficult to enter text for "custom" when rejecting suggested edit

Tags: bug, user-interface, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Focus jumps onto the Radiobutton if I click into the “Custom Rejection Reason Textbox”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112067/focus-jumps-onto-the-radiobutton-if-i-click-into-the-custom-rejection-reason-te)

When rejecting a suggested edit with a custom reason, it takes quite a lot of effort to dismiss the input placeholder. It often takes several clicks in the textarea before I'm given a chance to enter any text.

[image: Cannot enter reason to reject edit]

**Expected behaviour:** Upon selecting "custom" the focus should go to the textarea for me to immediatelty start entering text. In fact, I'm ok with having to then click on the text area to get the focus (but just once, please).

I cannot tell if this problem is browser specific as I'm currently stuck on a machine with only an ancient version of Firefox (3.6.20 - Linux), but IIRC I have experience the same issue on a newish Firefox (7.x.x? - Windows XP).

<strike>Can anyone else confirm this behaviour?</strike> ([related bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/112067/134327)).

*p.s. I can avoid this problem if I select "custom" then use <kbd>TAB</kbd> to switch the focus to the textarea.*

Comment: Ahh.. For some reason I missed that when searching.

Comment: Was about to delete this question, but decided against it. I'm guessing it'll be closed as dup eventually, but at least it can serve as a pointer to the first report and help others find it (and avoid further resubmissions). -- p.s. happy to delete if this is a silly excuse.

Comment: Not a silly excuse.