# Flagging enables the "I'm Done" button even when I'm out of flags 

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, review, late-answers

I am doing reviews in Late Answers section and by now I have 0 inform moderator flags remaining.

Here is what can be done to bypass the limits:

```
Select Flag
Select Not an answer
Press Flag answer
```

`"You can only flag for moderator attention 36 times per day"` message is shown, however **"I'm done"** button becomes active after this tick. Just press it and start the cheating over.

Any plans to fix it?

Comment: *Related?* [Focus jumps onto the Radiobutton if I click into the “Custom Rejection Reason Textbox”](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112067/focus-jumps-onto-the-radiobutton-if-i-click-into-the-custom-rejection-reason-te)

Comment: Arrrr...that's the wrong one. I had one which described a similar behavior based on those Focus-Problems (in the flagging dialog)...seems like that question is gone.

Comment: @Unicornified Bobby: could be, at least it is another similar bug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fixed now. An unsuccessful flag will no longer enable the "I'm Done" button.