# Revoking votes enables the “I'm Done” button and permits bypassing the votes limit

Tags: discussion, bug, review, late-answers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [The current review system encourages faux reviews: some people upvote everything rather than actually fixing it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149621/the-current-review-system-encourages-faux-reviews-some-people-upvote-everything)

I am doing reviews in Late Answers section and by now I have 2 votes to cast remaining.

Here is what can be done to bypass the votes limit:

1. Upvote the answer
2. Ctrl+click on the user name to open his user profile in a new tag
3. Press `I'm done` button
4. Go to the user profile, go to the lates upvote and click it again

The upvote will be deducted and one can use it to "review" the next answer.

This is related to [Flagging enables the "I'm Done" button even when I'm out of flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148406/186246) , however it could be much more difficult to find a reasonable solution for this.

Is it possible to fix it?

**Added:** Same problem appears here: [I'm Done button remain enabled even after the action is rolled back in First Posts Review](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147196/186246)

Comment: There are many trick for that. e.g. Comment to post and remove it from a question page. Or upvote comment and un-upvote comment from a question page. etc...

Comment: Their still working on that I had a similiar question about retagging